# Are spelling errors in my rejection letter an HR trap or an act of negligence?

Tags: hiring-process, rejection

Recently I have had an interview for QA technician, where good knowledge of spelling and grammar were essential.

Unfortunately I didn't get the job, but one thing still bothers me. The rejection message contained 2 very serious spelling errors and 1 stylistics. That is a lot for 3 sentences (less than 200 characters).

Is this some kind of HR trap/test? This is very weird situation and I don't know how to handle it...

What kind of signal(s) is/are a company sending out when their routine correspondence contains obvious spelling and grammatical errors? Can I gain anything by replying with corrections?  Should I respond to a rejection worded this way even to say 'thanks for letting me know'?

Comment: Are you talking about errors in their message telling you, you didn't get the job?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant

Comment: Was this an informal reply sent with a mobile device or a formalized email?

Comment: formalized email
@jmorc English is my 3rd language. Please have some understanding :)

Comment: @user1075940 Sorry :)   For what it's worth, I think this is a decent question, I'm not sure why all the downvotes

Comment: @user1075940 - You escaped the trap.  Would you have wanted to work for a company that couldn't spell? (More specifically, that was hiring people of questionable literacy?) Would you have taken the job if the acceptance letter had that many errors?

Comment: @user1075940 I'm guessing that people vote this question down for being primarily opinion based. Maybe there's a way to re-word what you're asking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's negligence.

Consider yourself fortunate that you're not going to be working in a company that values quality so little.

If you saw this in an earlier communication (i.e., the invitation to an interview) it might have been a poor trap.  Since they've indicated they are not interested in you it's safe to assume this is nothing more than sloppiness.

I would ignore the errors and move on.

Answer (score 9):

Ignore the typos. You didn't get the job, so they aren't trying to trap you. Remember it is the QA technician who has to have the excellent grammar and spelling skills, not the HR person who composed the letter.

Comment: I personally would expect a HR person to have good grammar and spelling, but my expectations would often not be met :-(